# openxlsx: load/save workbook as character only

Tags: r

I need to do some formating on  an existing Excel workbook (and leave anything else as is). My current approach is:

```
library(openxlsx)

# Open file
wb <- loadWorkbook("C:/myfile.xlsx")

# Formatting
mystyle <- createStyle(border = "Left" )
addStyle(wb, sheet = "Sheet1", style = mystyle, row = 1, cols = 2, gridExpand = T)

# Save
saveWorkbook(wb, "C:/myresult.xlsx", overwrite = T)
```

**Problem:** Some cells (i.e. blank ones) in the original workbook are interpreted as numeric and consequently displayed as `NA` (instead of a blank cell) in the saved file.

While `openxlsx::write.xlsx()` allows for handling of `NA` (i.e. `keepNA`), [`saveWorkbook`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/openxlsx/versions/4.2.5.1/topics/saveWorkbook) and [`loadWorkbook`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/openxlsx/versions/4.2.5.1/topics/loadWorkbook) do not provide this option. I would prefer not to write single sheets using `openxlsx::write.xlsx()` etc.

**Question:** How can I declare a whole workbook "as character" or otherwise avoid the display of `NA` (instead of a blank cell) in the saved Excel file?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly this is a known behavior of `openxlsx` see  [e.g. #359](https://github.com/ycphs/openxlsx/issues/359). As stated in the issue this is unlikely to change. You could give `openxlsx2` a try if you like.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem but `saveWorkbook` display blanck cell when is NA as you want.
Did you try update `openxlsx` ?

```
library(openxlsx)

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "test")
writeData(wb, "test", c(1, NA, 2), startCol = 1, startRow = 1)

mystyle <- createStyle(border = "Left")
addStyle(wb, sheet = "test", style = mystyle,
         row = 1, cols = 2, gridExpand = T)
  
saveWorkbook(wb, "C:/Users/pc36957/Documents/myresult.xlsx", overwrite = T)
```

**EDIT :** Problem doesn't come from openxlsx version. An alternative method seems to be to temporarily extract the values from the sheet with `readWorkbook` and rewrite them with the `keepNA = F` argument of `writeData`.

```r
# Open file
wb <- loadWorkbook("C:/myfile.xlsx")

# temporarily extract sheet as df
temp <- readWorkbook(wb, sheet = "Sheet1", skipEmptyRows = F)

# rewrite data to same sheet
writeData(wb, "Sheet1", temp, keepNA = F, startCol = 1, startRow = 1)

# Formatting
mystyle <- createStyle(border = "Left" )
addStyle(wb, sheet = "Sheet1", style = mystyle, row = 1, cols = 2, gridExpand = T)

# Save saveWorkbook
(wb, "C:/myresult.xlsx", overwrite = T)
```

Comment: I'm on version 4.2.5, so this should be fine. Default of writeData is keepNA=FALSE, when you set keepNA=TRUE, the NA are displayed (this is what happens to me when I only load and save the workbook as described in the question.

Comment: Is that possible to share a test file ? I tried creating an xlsx with empty cell, load it and saev it by using your code but there is no NA displayed.